# Is there a way to change the default theme of a site collection and fututre subsites?

Tags: site-collection, theme, sub-site

I am trying to brand our extranet in SP 2013.  The site collection is using the OOB "Orange" theme.  When I create a subsite, the subsite uses the default SharePoint 2013 theme.  I can go back and change the look to the "Orange" theme, but is there a way to change the default for the site collection and all subsites to the "Orange" theme?  Or is there a checkbox I missed somewhere that will cascade the theme choice to all subsites in this site collection?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very sure whether we can do that with UI.

Making use of event receivers we can apply the chosen theme after the site is created.

Sample code:

```
SPFile spColorFile = targetWeb.GetFile(targetWeb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/_catalogs/theme/15/Palette002.SPCOLOR"); 

SPTheme spTheme = SPTheme.Open("ProgrammedTheme", spColorFile);

spTheme.ApplyTo(targetWeb, true);
```